# Show Record details when we click lookup icon

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]
When ever I click record for ex 001 I want to display details of that  particular record

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take some time to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the tour. Right now it's not clear what you want to do exactly - just see the details (then use search Search Layouts), or open another window with record details. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/228157/edit) and be more specific.

Comment: You are clicking this lookup field on Standard detail page correct?  I believe it's custom object and after click on what are all the details you want to show on the page.  Generally Salesforce will allow you to show only Name on the lookup field.  Give some inputs to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Lookup Dialog Layout" to include the fields you'd like to see.

Using "Accounts" as an example, go to "Accounts > Search Layouts > Lookup Dialogs", then add any fields you'd like.

You could also create a custom page, which displays related records information when you select one of the records, but thats effort & code.